# Cavalier advice

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I am currently playing a game in which there's a Barbarian, Rogue, Sorcerer, Wizard, Ranger, and a Cavalier (me). I'm trying to make him be able to fight in close combat (mainly) but still be able to fight on griffon back if needed (to scout ahead). I also want him to deal out damage, while still being able to have an high defence. I am not sure on what feats or stats to improve on as I level up?

> Race: Human
>   Class: Cavalier
>   Traits: Reactionary, and Law enforcer
>
> Stats:
>
> - Strength: 13+2+1 (not including giants belt)
> - Dex: 14
> - Con: 12
> - Int: 12
> - Wis: 10
> - Cha: 14
>
> Hp: 80
>
> Ac: 20 (22 with shield)
>
> Order: order of the flame (gm allowed)
>
> Feats:
>
> - Racial feat: Quickdraw
> - Level 1 feat: toughness
> - Cavalier bonus feat: Stealth synergy
> - Level 3 feat: weapon focus (great axe)
> - Level 5 feat: power attack
> - Level 6 cavalier bonus feat: Furious focus
> - Level 7 feat: Monstrous mount (just leveled up)
>
> Armour + shield: Full plate masterwork, and Darkwood shield
>
> Weapons: +1 greataxe, +1 Long sword, and a long bow
>
> Magical Items: +2 giants strength belt, Darkwood shield

Comment: These are really two questions; one is dealing with character advancement, the other with in-character party cohesion.

Comment: Even with the edit, I think this is too broad. What are you trying to achieve with the character? What do you want to focus on? What parts of playing do you enjoy the most?

Comment: As Wibbs is getting at, we can't really give build advice to questions that are just: "here's my build, how can I improve it." We also need another ingredient: what direction you want to go in. There's _lots_ of potential ways to play most characters, so possible build directions go far and wide. We need you to tell us which direction _you_ want to go in so that we can help you go there.

Comment: A level 7 griffon-riding cavalier that can scout and that specializes in close combat is specific enough for me. Voting to reopen.